# Fedora 16 dependency hell

Tags: fedora, package-management, rpm, libraries, dependencies

There's a package `libvpx-0.9.7` which is required by empathy application. Now I want to install another application which requires `libvpx-1.0`... Update is not allowed because some applications depend on the old version. What's the solution to this situation?

Comment: Have you installed packages from somewhere other than the official Fedora repositories?  What is this "other application" you're trying to install?  Where does it come form?

Comment: I'm trying to install skype, it requires libQtGui.so.4 which is not installed because of the versions conflict

Comment: What is the package that requires libvpx-0.9.7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm running Fedora 16 and Skype.  And I have Empathy installed.  Empathy does not have any requirement (either explicit or implicit) on libvpx:

```
# rpm -q --requires empathy | grep -i vpx
```

And in fact, very few things depend on it directly:

```
# rpm -e libvpx
error: Failed dependencies:
    libvpx.so.1()(64bit) is needed by (installed) xulrunner-10.0-1.fc16.x86_64
    libvpx.so.1()(64bit) is needed by (installed) gstreamer-plugins-bad-free-0.10.22-2.fc16.2.x86_64
```

I have this Skype package installed:

```
# rpm -q skype
skype-2.2.0.35-fc10.i586
```

And this version of libvpx:

```
# rpm -q libvpx
libvpx-1.0.0-1.fc16.x86_64
```

In fact, libvpx 0.9.7 does not appear to be available in the Fedora 16 repositories.

I would make sure that all your existing packages have actually come from the Fedora 16 repositories.

Comment: skype requires libQtGui.so.4, libQtGui.so.4 is not installed because of many "Protected multilib versions:..." -version conflicts.